# Journey Builder: Email Send Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

In my journey, entrants get admitted into it, but emails arent been sent. When I check the history, they have the following status:

> Failed: Email.JourneyBuilder.Activities.EmailAddress: Error binding
>   data bound member

What does this mean and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means the email address is not present in your All subscribers list. To overcome this issue in Journey entry setting select contact data and in default channel address select use an email address from entry source only (Select this option to tell Journey Builder to use the email address associated to each contact in the entry source. This option is best for journeys that admit contacts that are not currently part of the Marketing Cloud system).

[image][image][image][image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUM]eI.png

Comment: a screenshot will help other members to understand your answer and it will help a lot

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekMishra. I have done all this and still have the same problem. I am using a "Date Based Event" as this is a bday program. and the system says contact data will be deprecated soon. Should I be using contact data?

Comment: The DE I am using is not set as root could this be why? I would also like to know what software you are using to make notes on your screen shot

Comment: @Data_Kid yes, use contact data and irrespective of whether you are setting the DE as root or not this should work. This is normal MSPAINT, you can use Nimbus screenshot application for making notes